# How to set discount when you buy 2 or more but limited to same SKU

Tags: cart, discount

E.g
A store wants to run a promotion to offer 10% off when purchase 10 or more of the SAME item(SKU).

Here comes a customers buys:
1 x Scarf (Pink)
1 x Scarf (White)
10 x Scarf (Red)

But Magento gives 10% of all the above 12 scarves instead of just the 10 red scarves.

What shall be done to solve it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create `shopping cart price rule`
 with your condition in Armin panel.

Refer this [**link**](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/shopping-cart-price-rules-in-magento-walk-through/)